# Swift: UnstableMutableRawPointer iteration

Tags: swift

I'm trying to iterate through an UnstableMutableRawPointer and change each 32-bit address with some operation, but I'm having trouble with it. First, it does not conform to subscripting nor iterations.

I looked at some articles for converting to UnstableMutablePointer with the assumingmemoryBounds method but it only gives a pointee method which is one 32 byte address.

Can someone "point" me to not the right memory address but the right technique to use for swift 3.0 up?

Comment: "32-bit address" So are you trying to iterate UInt32s?

Comment: Yep but it's time critical, so i need to manipulate it fast.

Comment: So why don't you rebind the `MutableRawPointer` into a `MutablePointer<UInt32>`?

Comment: Tried. I might be doing it wrong but once bound to UnsafeMutablePointer I am actually instantiating a new pointer it seems and still can't subscript or iterate over

Comment: Of course you're making a "new pointer", but it points to the same memory as the raw pointer did, except now with more type information. You can use that `UnsafeMutable`Pointer to initialize a `UnsafeMutableBuffer`, which conforms to `Collection`.